# Telethon: Leave a chat not a channel request

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I am using the `Telethon` Telegram client library. I need to leave a `Chat` but there is only one request for leaving and that is `LeaveChannelRequest`.
But as the name says, It is for `Channels` and not `Chats`.

`Channels` have both `chat_id` and `access_hash` but `Chats` only have `chat_id`.

How can I leave a `Chat`?

I have checked the `tdlib` library and it has a thing called `CloseChat` which seems to suit what I need, How can I use it here in `telethon`?
https://javadoc.tlgrm.ru/org/drinkless/td/libcore/telegram/TdApi.CloseChat.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to kick yourself with [`DeleteChatUserRequest`](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/messages/delete_chat_user.html):

```
client(functions.messages.DeleteChatUserRequest(
    chat_id=chat_id,
    user_id='me'
))
```

You can also use [`dialog.delete()`](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.dialog.Dialog.delete):

```
for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
    if dialog.id == chat_id:
        dialog.delete()
```

On more recent versions, the above can be improved by using [`client.delete_dialog`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.delete_dialog) instead:

```
client.delete_dialog(chat_id)
```